# LLVMContext as class member breaks constructors?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I’m trying to make an `LLVMContext` member variable in a class `Application`. MCVE:

```
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>

struct Foo {};

class Application {
public:
  Application(int a, Foo foo, int b);
private:
  llvm::LLVMContext context_;
};

void function() {
  auto application = Application(12, Foo(), 21);
}
```

Adding the variable, however, produces some very strange errors: (Clang 4.0.1 and Apple LLVM version 8.1.0)

> ```
> toy.cpp:13:8: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Application'
>   auto application = Application(12, Foo(), 21);
>        ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> toy.cpp:5:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: expects an l-value
>       for 1st argument
> class Application {
>       ^
> toy.cpp:7:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
>   Application(int a, Foo foo, int b);
>   ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

What is going on here? Why does Clang think I’m trying to use a constructor with one argument ("but 1 was provided")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`llvm::LLVMContext` is not a copyable class. It's copy c'tor is deleted, from the [documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html):

```
LLVMContext (LLVMContext &) = delete
```

Since you do copy initialization, the compiler has to check there is a viable copy c'tor for your class. But it's implicitly deleted on account of `llvm::LLVMContext`.

Unless you are using C++17 where copy-elision is guaranteed and the compiler can avoid the check, just get rid of the `auto` type declaration:

```
Application application {12, Foo(), 21};
```

Comment: Gosh. Thanks. I was so fixated on finding an error in the class definition I completely overlooked that.